# Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: libs/com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have this error:

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: libs/com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
```

Here my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: `com.android.application`

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.guestadmin.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'libs/com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    }
```

Comment: anyone can tell me why i am getting this 30-13 error plz

Comment: Have you checked, whether the appcompat.v7:22.2.1 Library is referenced correctly? Maybe your version has changed or it cannot not found? I would remove the reference again and add it back in, if you still require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
compile 'libs/com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

You are using the wrong syntax - you can have a dependency with a single jar or multiple jar files.
With a single jar file you can add:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/local_dependency.jar')
}
```

It's possible to add a directory of jars to compile.

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

In any case you are still importing all the jar files in your project since you are using:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

but pay attention to import a support library in this way.
You are just importing that file since you are using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

and also this library has other dependencies and resource file, so it would give you an error.